# Is it possible to replace wgl/glx by cgl in Gtk2 for OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, gtk

The Homebrew version of gtk+ has recently moved to a pure Quartz version without X11. In our project we have been using glx to initialise the OpenGL context and set up the a Gtk viewport for OpenGL on both Linux and OSX (and wgl on Windows). This has now broken on OSX.

I am now searching for a way to get a handle on a Gtk widget window and use an opengl context created by CGL to draw to it. I did not write the original code so I am a bit at a loss.

With wgl the interesting part looks like this (`widget` contains the pointer to the `GtkWidget` which will be replaced by an OpenGL view):

```
HWND window = (HWND)GDK_WINDOW_HWND(::gtk_widget_get_window(widget));
HDC  drawingContext = ::GetDC(window);
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pixelFormatDescriptor;

// Insert some PixelFormat initialisation here
int pixelFormatIdentifier = ChoosePixelFormat(drawingContext, &pixelFormatDescriptor);
SetPixelFormat(drawingContext, pixelFormatIdentifier, &pixelFormatDescriptor)

HGLRC GLRenderingContext = wglCreateContext(drawingContext);
```

On Linux (with gdkx) it is initialized in this way:

```
::GdkScreen* screen = ::gdk_screen_get_default();
::Display* display = GDK_SCREEN_XDISPLAY(screen);
::gint screenNumber = GDK_SCREEN_XNUMBER(screen);

int visualInfoAttributes[]=
{
    GLX_RGBA,
    GLX_RED_SIZE,    1,
    GLX_GREEN_SIZE,  1,
    GLX_BLUE_SIZE,   1,
    GLX_ALPHA_SIZE,  1,
    GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER,
    GLX_DEPTH_SIZE,  1,
    None
};
::XVisualInfo* visualInfo = ::glXChooseVisual(display, screenNumber, visualInfoAttributes);
::GLXContext glRenderingContext = glXCreateContext(display, visualInfo, NULL, False);
```

and then before drawing to the widget the context is set in this way:

```
::Window window = GDK_WINDOW_XID(gtk_widget_get_window(widget));
::glXMakeCurrent(display, window, glRenderingContext);
```

How can (if at all) achieve this using CGL? I would prefer to stay in C++ as the project currently does not use any Objective-C code and I would prefer to not include any external libraries (SDL and co.).

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but in GTK 3.16 and later, you should be able use `GtkGLArea` for this. It is unfortunately not implemented for OSX. The progress is tracked on [this bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740199), I tried to get it working at one point, but don't know enough about CGL. You might be able to base your solution on that, and perhaps if it works, you could contribute a working `GtkGLArea` back to GTK.